# If $f''(x)\geq 0$ on $(a, b)$ then show that $f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)\leq \alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y).$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f(x)$ be a function such that $f''(x)\geq 0$ on $(a, b)$ then applyint MVT show that for all $x,y\in (a, b)$ and for all $\alpha \in [0,1]$
$$f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)\leq \alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y).$$

I know that I have to use Lagrange's MVT, but I don't understand how to use it here. Please help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality

Comment: There is a simple picture which will help you!

Comment: Informally: $f''(x)$ gives that $f'(x)$ is increasing, hence the slope of the tangent lines increases when travelling from left to right. In particular, that implies the graph of $f(x)$ lies above the graph of any tangent, so $f(x)$ is a convex function.

Comment: Both conditions can be treated as independent definitions of a convex function.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Would you please elaborate in answer style

Comment: @StubbornAtom: I do not agree with that. Convexity does not imply that $f''$ exists, but $f''\geq 0$ implies convexity. So they are not equivalent conditions, and they are *very* dependent.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio My bad, you are spot on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, let $x<y$. Clearly $x<\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y<y$. Applying Lagrange' MVT in $[x,\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y], [\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y,y]$ respectively, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)-f(x)&=&f'(c_1)(1-\alpha)(y-x), c_1\in(x,\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y), \\
f(y)-f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)&=&f'(c_2)\alpha(y-x), c_2\in(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y,y).
\end{eqnarray}
Cleary $c_1<c_2$. Since $f''(x)\ge 0$, one has that $f'(x)$ is non-decreasing and hence $f'(c_1)\le f'(c_2)$ or
$$ \frac{1}{1-\alpha}[f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)-f(x)]\le\frac{1}{\alpha}[f(y)-f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)].$$
Thus one has
$$ f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)\le \alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y). $$

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x,y\in[a,b]$ (let us suppose that $x<y$) and consider, for all $\alpha\in[0,1]$ :

$$\phi(\alpha)=\alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(y)-f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)$$

Now compute :

$$\phi'(\alpha)=f(x)-f(y)-(x-y)f'(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)$$

By MVT, there exists some $c\in(x,y)$ such that $f(x)-f(y)=(x-y)f'(c)$;

Thus :

$$\phi'(\alpha)=(x-y)(f'(c)-f'(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y))$$

Let us denote :$$\alpha_0=\frac{y-c}{y-x}$$

Since $f'$ is increasing, we can conclude that $\phi$ is increasing for $x\in[0,\alpha_0]$ and decreasing for $x\in[\alpha_0,1]$.

But $\phi(0)=\phi(1)=0$, so that $\forall\alpha\in[0,1],\,\phi(\alpha)\ge0$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Actually your $c$ is between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Oops ! Thank you. I am editing it right now.